# §12.3.2 [class.conv.fct]/1 in C++1z changed substantially in relation to C++14. Does it make sense?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, c++17

§12.3.2 [class.conv.fct]/1 in C++14:

> A member function of a class X having no parameters with a name of the
>   form
>
> *conversion-function-id*:
>          **operator**
>   *conversion-type-id*
>       *conversion-type-id*:
>          *type-specifier-seq*
>   *conversion-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>       *conversion-declarator*:
>          *ptr-operator*
>   *conversion-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> specifies a conversion from X to the type specified by the
>   *conversion-type-id*. Such functions are called conversion functions. No return type can be specified. If a conversion function is a member
>   function, the type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is “function
>   taking no parameter returning conversion-type-id”. ...

§12.3.2 [class.conv.fct]/1 in C++1z: (the relevant changes are highlighted below)

> A member function of a class X having no parameters with a name of the
>   form
>
> *conversion-function-id*:
>          **operator**
>   *conversion-type-id*
>       *conversion-type-id*:
>          *type-specifier-seq*
>   *conversion-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>       *conversion-declarator*:
>          *ptr-operator*
>   *conversion-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> specifies a conversion from X to the type specified by the *conversion-type-id*. Such functions are called conversion functions. **A *decl-specifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a conversion function (if any) shall be neither
>   a *defining-type-specifier* nor static**. Type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is “function taking no parameter returning *conversion-type-id*”. ...

I can't think of a conversion function without a *decl-specifier-seq*, or with a *decl-specifier-seq* that doesn't contain a *defining-type-specifier*. As far as I can understand, that would mean a *conversion-function-id*, whose *conversion-type-id* doesn't have a type!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *conversion-type-id* contains no *decl-specifier-seq*; it contains a *type-specifier-seq*.

That quote is about this *decl-specifier-seq* in the conversion function's declaration/definition:

```
struct C {
    constexpr inline explicit operator int() const { return 0; }
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    operator float() const;
// ^ no decl-specifier-seq here
};
```

which, for obvious reasons, cannot contain a *defining-type-specifier*.

The point of the change is that it's misleading to say "no return type can be specified" when the return type is determined by the *conversion-type-id*.